# How can I programmatically set all rendering to use specific graphics card?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, drivers

I am trying to figure out how to use specific drivers for specific users on my pc.  I want to do this programatically.

So basically what I am trying to figure out is how can I set a session or user to use specific drivers? Is their registry values I can change?

I want to be able to change all rendering on a specific user session to use a different graphics card.  Can this be done?

Comment: This sounds to me like an XY problem - what are you ACTUALLY trying to achieve? Surely one PC has one or more graphics cards, each graphics card connected to one or more monitors?

Comment: I want to pro grammatically select which device/drivers that a user is using in their session. I have two graphics cards on my pc, one optimum for gaming, other for everything else. I want to be able to have a user account created that is tweaked for optimum gaming settings, and one I use for work. All I basically need to know is how to programatically change what display device is in use. I am thinking WMI could help me out here.